# Firebase getToken not working after changed Service Worker

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

For Firebase 9.5.0 push notifications, we have a service worker that receives firebase push, the service workers all work fine.

However, we're migrating from an old service worker registration (from a 3rd party) to our own, brand new users all work fine registering and getting a token, but we get an error when we want to use a new service worker for an existing registered user (with an old service-worker from a 3rd party).

The error happens on `getToken` which causes the error

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: 
Request is missing required authentication credential. 
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

I'm hoping we can add some code in the `catch` to do something like reregister the user or something, but looking through the firebase docs, I can't find anything how we would register the user with ourselves without an error ?

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js";
import { deleteToken, getMessaging, getToken, isSupported, onMessage  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-messaging.js";


const firebaseConfig = { 
   apiKey: ...
   authDomain: ...
   projectId: ...
   storageBucket: ...
   messageSenderId: ...
   appId: ...
   measurementId: ...
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

const registerServiceWorker = () => {
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

     navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworkerfilename.js')
      .then( function( registration) {
        console.log('reg successful', registration); // gets here ok
        
        getToken( messaging, { serviceWorkerRegistration: registration } )
         .then(function(currentToken) {
           // do stuff, this normally works for a new user, but not on old service worker
         })
        .catch( function(err) {

           // always gets here for old user from old service worker
           Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
             console.log(permission); // gets here, and shows 'granted', but stuck from here what we can do to reset the user
           });

         });

      })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got around this firstly with a check to check with filename the serviceworker had

```
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.scriptURL.match(<someregex>)
```

And then if wanted, unregister the existing service worker...

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then( function(registrations) { 
    for(let registration of registrations) { 
      registration.unregister(); 
    } 
  });
```

And then if necessary, call a function to register again.